# What's the difference between EC2 Reserved Instance Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC) and Linux/UNIX?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-reserved-instances

My instance is running on Linux (kubernetes deployed by kops). From the billing I saw they are classified as "Linux/UNIX", but I think it is deployed in VPC via kops.

Now I want to buy reserved instance, and the choices of platform has two:

- Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC)
- Linux/UNIX

Which one should I use? What are the difference?

BTW, once I bought a RI, do I have to wait to the next day to see the reservation coverage from billing UI? Can I see if it covers some of my running instance immediately?

Comment: may be related https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=166972  please note the ec2-classic is deprecated. EC2-classic (no vpn) is deprecated, check if you have a vpn reference on your ec2 instance (in the console)

Answer (score 1):

I have access to multiple aws accounts and I found something interesting.

As of today (2020-02-26), when looking at `ca-central-1` region's platforms when trying to buy reserved instances, I only see `Linux/UNIX`, and I don't see `Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC)` in the list:

[image: ca-central-1-purchase-reserved-instances-platforms]

This list is the same in both older and recent AWS accounts.

When I look at `us-east-1` region's platforms when trying to buy reserved instances, I see the same list as `ca-central-1` when using the recent account **But when I use a much older aws account which used to have `m1` ec2 instances (which can't be created anymore), here's what I see:

[image]

Note that we already reserved a plan for an `m1` instance back in the days (which is now expired) so that could be related to why I see two kind platform for each of them.

Funny thing is I can only reserve `Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC)`, not `Linux/UNIX` as you can see from the two screenshots:

Linux/UNIX list empty on older account:

[image: Linux/UNIX list empty on older account]

Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC) list not empty on older account:

[image: Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC) list not empty on older account]

So my assumption is if you see both, `Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC)` will be the one you need, otherwise, use `Linux/UNIX`.

Update 2020-02-27: I did purchase them, I will verify usage once it's effective, but I'm quite sure everything is fine.

Update 2020-03-06: I confirm it works as expected. I have 100% coverage in both regions starting from 2020-02-27 in the billing dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Linux/UNIX is EC2-Classic which is legacy.

"The EC2-Classic platform was introduced in the original release of Amazon EC2."

[AWS EC2-Classic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-classic-platform.html)

Use Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC) which will spawn the instance in your own VPC.